# Open bounty by non-poster of question that has a solution?

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer

Came across this today on a question I had closed as resolved quite some time ago:

[How do I keep my cacert.pem current for security reasons when using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032165/where-is-the-official-download-location-for-cacert-pem)

It now shows an open bounty, even though there is a viable answer to the question. Specific links to where the latest cert files can be found officially have been posted.

Could someone enlighten me as to the following :

- Why is there a bounty on a question that has a solution?
- How can someone else open a bounty on a question they didn't post?
- Is this a bug?

Comment: This is all part of how bounties work. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely not a bug, it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

There is no such thing as "Closed as Resolved" on any Stack Exchange site.  Yes you might have accepted an answer, but that doesn't signal the end of your questions life or usefulness.  Users with the same problem may find your question while doing their own research.  Maybe your answer helped them, but maybe it didn't.  Questions (and their answers) are expected to stand test of time and be useful for everyone (not just you) both now and in the future.

So if a user who has the same problem isn't satisfied with the answers?  They have 3 choices:

- Keep looking.  If they keep looking and find the answer, they might come back to your question and leave their own answer to help future visitors.
- Ask the same question again (this is not consider acceptable on Stack Exchange site and a new identical question would be closed as a duplicate of yours).
- Try to draw attention to your question to get new answers.  This is why the user is trying to do by placing the bounty on it.

So let's look at the custom bounty text written by the user who opened the bounty to see what they are looking for:

> Are there any more authoritative sources than a site run by four friendly programmers?

Given this, the user is looking for a *better* resource from a more authoritative source than a random site run by 4 people.

You are under no obligation to do anything.  You have no control in awarding the bounty and you are not obligated to change your accepted answer.  Of course, if a another answer comes in and you find it better than your own, then you are free to change it if you want, but you have no obligation to do so.  Even if the bounty is awarded, you don't have to acknowledge that answer either

Comment: This is what I would have written if I had felt like writing more than a comment. Actually, my answer would probably not have been as good as this one.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.  I was quite confused when I saw that as I did not know others have options on questions already asked.